# ANSI X9.31 AES pseudocode or algorithm explanation

Tags: aes, pseudo-random-generator, notation

I want to write a program that will generate random data by using ANSI X9.31 with AES 128 bit, however I could find the standart only with cryptographic notation, and I did not understand it clearly.

```
I = ede *K(DT)
R = ede *K(I XOR V)
V = ede*K(R Xor I)
```

Could you explain me how the algorithms works or suggest me any document to understand it, I tried to understand from the notation but I could not. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: BTW: is there any specific reason you have to use ANSI X9.31?  The generators from NIST SP 800-90 are considerably better...

Comment: Yes it is kind of a project, that's the reason I have to use it, although there is better generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets go through the steps in detail:

```
I = ede*K(DT)
```

K is a long term secret key; that's a random value which is the key of X9.31; it's selected somehow (X9.31 doesn't specify how), and the security of the random numbers depends on it.  Because you are using AES, this would be a random 128 bit value.

When it says 'ede*K(X)', what X9.31 means is 'take the value X, and send it through the block cipher operation (in the encrypt direction).  X9.31 calls it `ede` because it was written in terms of 3DES (which is done by doing 3 DES operations, in ede mode); for you, you'd just replace it with a single AES encryption operation.

DT is the current date/time (which is updated for every iteration); for you, this would be a 128 bit value, and the format you select for how to express the current time doesn't matter.

The result is placed into a temporary location (called `I`)

```
R = ede*K(I XOR V)
```

V is the X9.31 current state (which also needs to be kept secret); for you, this is a 128 bit value.

In this step, you take the current state V, exclusive or that with the temp variable I generated in the previous step, send that though AES.

R is the 128 bits of output that X9.31 generates this iteration.

```
V = ede*K(R Xor I)
```

Here, you take the two values generated in the previous two steps, exclusive or them together, send them through AES; that's the updated X9.31 state you'll use for the next iteration.

And, remember, when you've done this, `R` contains the 128 random bits that you asked for...

Comment: so K means the initial seed that I will use to generate my random numbers?

Comment: @venturemoo: you could look at it as a 'seed', however, it's really the long term RNG key that never changes...

Comment: sorry for question again, how should I get the initial value of V at first?

Comment: @venturemoo: X9.31 doesn't specify; I don't believe that it is critical for security...